# How to get the Image from first page when search in Google?

Tags: android, image, google-search, wikipedia

Usually after using Google to search for a city, there is a part of Wikipedia page on the right with an image and a map. Can anyone tell me how I could access this image? I should know how to download it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the main image (that goes with the map image on the right) is very rarely from Wikipedia, so you can't use Wikipedia API to get it. If you want to access the actual main image you can use this:

```
private static void GetGoogleImage(string word)
{
    // make an HTTP Get request
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com.pg/search?q=" + word);
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36";
    using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            // get all images with base64 string
            var matches = Regex.Matches(reader.ReadToEnd(), @"'data:image/jpeg;base64,([^,']*)'");
            if (matches.Count > 0)
            {
                // get the image with the max height
                var bytes = matches.Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(x => Convert.FromBase64String(x.Groups[1].Value.Replace("\\75", "=").Replace("\\075", "=")))
                    .OrderBy(x => Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(x, false)).Height).Last();

                // save the image as 'image.jpg'
                using (var imageFile = new FileStream("image.jpg", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    imageFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    imageFile.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This work for me, and always returns the actual main image (if such exists). For example, `GetGoogleImage("New York")` give me [data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg...](http://oi66.tinypic.com/e5k4sj.jpg).

I use the fact that from the all base64 string images in response the main has the max height, so its need only to order them by height and to select the last one. If it's required, you can check here also for minimum image height. The replacing `\075` to `=` is needed [base64's padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding).

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need. But is there any chance that this is not made for Android? It doesn't recognise a lot of commands

Comment: @LaurynasG this is C#, my idea was to give the logic, then you can write it in every programming language. Sorry but I still don't know Java.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly I am not that experienced that I could manipulate languages and this web logic :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want Wikipedia article main image you have to use [Wikipedia API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&format=json&piprop=original&titles=Egypt).

**Update:**

- You can use jsoup: Java HTML Parser `org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3` which return list of image inside page.

  ```
      String stringResponse = getHtmlContent(url);
      Document doc = Jsoup.parse(stringResponse);
      Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
      //Get all elements with img tag ,
      Elements img = content.getElementsByTag("img");
      for (Element el : img) {
          //for each element get the src image url
          String src = el.attr("src");
          Log.d(TAG, "src attribute is : " + src);
          String alt = el.attr("alt");
          //do some stuff
      }
  ```

**Update:**
Wikipida provide API for to return [HTML Content](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Egypt&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=jsonfm)

Comment: problem is that Google usually uses nicer image from Wikipedia page

Comment: should I do this for Google or Wikipedia? And how to know which image it is? I think they all have different names and url addresses

Comment: @LaurynasG I used this lib with `wikipedia` page and each time main article pic returned as first item (NOT ensure that may be article without pic.), You have to look about  image tag may be unique property to depend on.